# How do I prove that there is a distance shorter than the length of 24in?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I have been given this following math problem:

> In a room 10 feet high, with a ceiling 16 feet long and 8 feet wide, there sits a fly, exactly on the center line of the narrow wall, 0.8 feet from the ceiling. On the opposite wall, also on the center line, sits a spider, 2.4 feet above the ground. The fly notices that the spider has just awakened, and addresses it,
>
> "Honorable spider, would you care to come over here and catch me?"
>
> "No, you would not give me enough time to reach you, but would fly away just in time."
>
> "Well, how fast do you intend crawling over here?” the fly asks.
>
> "When I was young, I used to be able to run pretty fast. But now, I am old. I cannot crawl more than 8 feet per minute."
>
> Upon hearing this, the fly replies sorrowfully,
>
> "Too bad, I cannot wait longer than three minutes. I shall sleep for that length of time, and then I must get into the sunshine."

Now this problem has stumped me because the solution tells me that **it is** possible, but does not tell me why. I simply thought the answer was not possible because the shortest distance from the spider to the fly was the distance on the remaining wall from the spider (10 - 2.4), the length of the prism (16) and the remaining distance to the fly (0.8) which is equal to 24.4.

$d = (10-2.4) + 16 + 0.8 = 24.4$

$t = \frac{d}{v} = \frac{24.4}{8} = 3.05$ min

This would mean that the spider would miss the fly by 3 seconds. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But it is possible and the spider can reach the fly before he wakes up.
[image]

Comment: Wow, literally just unfolding the prism in a certain way, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This ought to help... one of a number of unfoldings of the room.  Can you try others and take it from here?

[image]

and

[image]

But are you kidding????!!!! Shorter than $24$ inches?!?!  Not a chance!!

Comment: Perhaps OP made the Stonehenge set for Spinal Tap.

Comment: Hah!  Yes...  and now let's turn up the votes to 11.

Comment: BTW that's a 26-foot path according to GeoGebra, but there are paths following similar patterns that are shorter. Giving OP something to work on?

Comment: Looks like that path is 26 ft. I will keep trying, thanks!

Comment: It is possible!

Comment: @DavidK, and there is in deed a shorter path than 24 ft.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the diagram labeled "$11$ nets of a cube" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)).  The shortest path is a straight line on one of those nets.  You have to figure out the best way to "unfold" the cube.

Comment: This pointed me to a page about the Fly and Spider problem - turns out these are quite common. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_spider_and_the_fly_problem